# How to insert values in assosiative array with mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make array with key 'barang' that contains ids of barang in my database.
Here my code

```
while ($globalBarang = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlBarang)) {
     $arrayglobal["barang"] = array($globalBarang['id_brg']);
}
```

for now with print_r() it result

```
Array ( [barang] => Array ( [0] => SSB-001 ) )
```

What I want:

```
Array ( [barang] => Array ( [0] => BRS-001, 
                            [1] => GLP-001, 
                            [2] => SSB-001 ) )
```

Here my database if needed:
Database:
[image: Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the assignment, add each element with `[]` (and not as an array on the right)...

```
while ($globalBarang = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlBarang)) {
     $arrayglobal["barang"][] = $globalBarang['id_brg'];
}
```